# my value is more than the range of unsigned integer

Tags: c++, palindrome

i have this exercise:" consider some natural number n, if it is not a Palindrom number, change the order of the digits in reverse order and add the resulting number with the original number. If the sum is not a palindrom number, repeat the same procedure on that sum until a palindrom number is obtained. Whether the above process is finite for any n. If yes, print out the number of process "

ex

input:1 output: 0

input: 12 output: 1

my problem is when i encounter larger number such as 19170 it will be over the limit of unsigned long long int
It will also be great if anyone can explain or guide me to resources that can help me understand it further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool check (long long int n)
{
 long long int clone_n=n,count=0,ans=0;
 while (clone_n!=0)
 {
     clone_n/=10;
     count++;
 }
 clone_n=n;
 for(int i=count;i>=0;i--)
 {
     ans+=(clone_n%10)*pow(10,i-1);
     clone_n/=10;
 }
 if(ans==n)
 {
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}


long long int reverse(long long int n)
{
 long long int clone_n=n,count=0,ans=0;
 while (clone_n!=0)
 {
     clone_n/=10;
     count++;
 }
 clone_n=n;
 for(int i=count;i>=0;i--)
 {
     ans+=(clone_n%10)*pow(10,i-1);
     clone_n/=10;
 }
 return ans;
}

int main()
{
 long long int n,count=0;
 cin>>n;
 if(check(n))
 {
     cout<<0;
     return 0;
 }
 else
 {
     while(check(n)!=1)
     {
         count++;
         n+=reverse(n);
     }
 }
 cout<<count;
}
```

my code is also included in the link: https://ideone.com/0p7JJU

Comment: I didn't check, but if it really over the limit of unsigned long long, you may consider implementing Big Integer support for your exercise.

Comment: it seems like you never need to store the whole number in an integer variable. You need the input (can be a `std::string`), digits are `char` or `int` from 0-9

Comment: "...be great if anyone can explain or guide me to resources that can help me understand it further." its a trick question. They want you to hit the wall, realize that the naive approach fails, and find a different solution. Storing a value in a `long long int` that does not fit in a `long long int` is not a solution ;)

Comment: btw you are using signed integers, not unsigned ones

Comment: Even if the process does terminate, there are inputs that will overflow any fixed-precision type. (For instance, a Python program with the input 19170 hadn't finished when I interrrupted it at a 2,947-digit number.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number

Answer (score 1):

The natural number that will not terminate the algorithm that the OP describe is called Lychrel number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number

It is currently unknown if any of these number exists, as correctly guessed by zkoza in the above answer, 196 is the smallest candidate to be a Lychrel number.

So, this is a specifically hard problem to tackle, however, I would like to address the specific overflow issue that the OP is facing. As pointed out by largest_prime_is_463035818 in the comments, there is no actual needs of any integer representation.

```
#include <iostream>

//take advantage of the fact that std::string use contiguous memory
bool is_palindrome(const char* first, const char* last)
{
    --last;
    while(first < last) {
        if (*first != *last)
            return false;
        ++first;
        --last;
    }
    return true;
}

std::string reverse_and_add(const std::string& digits)
{
    size_t size = digits.size();
    //the result string will be at least the same length
    std::string result(size,'0');
    int carry_over = 0;
    int ascii_zero = 48;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        int front = digits.at(i) - ascii_zero;
        int back = digits.at(size - i - 1) - ascii_zero;
        int sum = front + back + carry_over;
        carry_over = sum / 10;
        int digit = sum >= 10 ? sum - 10 : sum;
        result[size - i - 1] = static_cast<char>(digit + ascii_zero);
    }
    //if at the last step we have a carry over we need to add an extra digit to
    //the string
    if (carry_over > 0)
        result = static_cast<char>(carry_over + ascii_zero) + result;
    return result;
}

void check(const std::string& s, int max_iteration)
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::string v(s);
    while(!is_palindrome(v.c_str(), v.c_str() + v.size()) && counter < max_iteration)
    {
        v = reverse_and_add(v);
        if (counter % 1000 == 0 && counter > 0)
            std::cout << "progressing iteration: " << counter << " string size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter == max_iteration)
        std::cout << "No result found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "result: " << counter << std::endl;
} 

int main()
{
    int max_iteration = 50000;
    check("187",max_iteration); // -> return 23
    check("19170", max_iteration); // -> doesn't find a solution
                                   // the final string is thousands of characters
}
```

***UPDATE***

Just for fun, I run 196 till 1000000 digits (that it took 3 years to complete 1987) and it produce the same result in about an hour and half (these hardware engineers are amazing).

result: 2415836
./a.out  5315.83s user 21.29s system 99% cpu 1:29:12.58 total

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a homework question.

The first number for which the sequence does not seem to be finite is as small as 196. I terminated a program after it hit 300000 digits.

What can you do?

Write a similar program where you implement your own "big numbers". It's an easy task, because all you need is addition of two same-length numbers, reversal, checking for being a palindrom, perhaps printing.   You can use `std::vector` or `std::string`.
Then, introduce an ad hoc threshold, like 100 or 1000 iterations. If the sequence will reach the threshold, stop it and return `false`.

It is possible that you did not present here the complete, detailed description of the problem. I found a similar problem on the internet, but with an explicit threshold of 5 iterations.  Or perhaps it is a problem that you've invented yourself, unaware of its complexity? Or the teacher is pulling your leg? Or I made a mistake in my code.

A famous example of a problem that has a simple formulation but no known solution is the  Collatz conjecture, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture . It can't be ruled out that your problem is of a similar type.

Here, for reference, is my solution for numbers from 180 to 195 (the first number in the sequence, the number of iteration, the last number in the sequence)

> 180   3   747
> 181   0   181
> 182   6   45254
> 183   4   13431
> 184   3   2552
> 185   3   4774
> 186   3   6996
> 187   23  8813200023188
> 188   7   233332
> 189   2   1881
> 190   7   45254
> 191   0   191
> 192   4   6996
> 193   8   233332
> 194   3   2992
> 195   4   9339

Answer (score 0):

Instead of numeric data type you can use string to store the values and do addition by parsing the whole string like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "759579537575937593759387";
    std::string s2 = "9956775659653876536535637653";

    int n1=s1.size()-1,n2=s2.size()-1;
    std::string s3 = "";
    uint8_t carry = 0;
    while(n1>=0 && n2>=0){
        uint8_t num1 = (int)s1[n1--] - 48;
        uint8_t num2 = (int)s2[n2--] - 48;
        uint8_t sum = char(num1+num2) + carry;
        carry = sum/10; // to get carry
        sum = sum%10;
        s3.insert(0,1,char(sum+48));
    }
    while(n1>=0)
    {
        uint8_t sum = carry + (int)s1[n1--] - 48;
        carry = sum/10;
        sum = sum%10;
        s3.insert(0,1,char(sum+48));
    }

    while(n2>=0)
    {
        uint8_t sum = carry + (int)s2[n2--] - 48;
        carry = sum/10;
        sum = sum%10;
        s3.insert(0,1,char(sum+48));
    }
    if (carry)
        s3.insert(0,1,char(carry+48));
    std::cout<<s3<<std::endl;
}
```

also you check if they are palindromic or not using two pointer method.
The above sum which I get is `9957535239191452474129397040`, there is no limit to addition by this method